# Word for position and direction

Tags: mathematics, abstract-nouns

I'm looking for a word that encapsulates both an object's position and direction.

Similar words:

- a "point" has just a position.
- a "vector" has a direction and magnitude
- an "orientation" has just a direction

I'm ideally looking for a short simple word, however I'm also interested in any mathsey words which may describe the concept.

Comment: In what sense does a position *have* a direction?

Comment: To clarify, a position might have a direction with respect to another point (position); but in that case the "direction" is in fact the direction of a *vector* pointing from the second position to the first.

Comment: @MattGutting, I can be standing at a position, and facing north.  I'm looking for a word, if there is one, to represent this pair of details.  I've seem some places use the word "node", but it's not really correct, so am seeing if there's a better one.

Comment: I know in one sense it is a vector from point origin, facing in the direction of another vector (ignoring the magnitude on the second).  But a VectorVector didn't really seem like the best one could come up with...

Comment: Ah, you're looking for a word denoting a view from a point?

Comment: @MattGutting, I'm more looking for a word to describe where an object is.  I placed the chess piece not just at this position, not just facing this direction, but at this... placement?

Comment: You're out of luck, I think, as far as a single word is concerned.

Comment: As explained by @mike663 the term in mathematics (and graphics) is usually **ray**. A surface normal, for example, is a vector, but that information along with it's position along the surface would make it a ray, whether or not the *idea* of a "ray" sounds correct or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In robotics, computer vision and mechanics, **pose** of an object refers to combination of its position *and* orientation.

Note that aforementioned word perhaps makes sense in science community and not necessarily in normal daily conversations (the question has mathematics tag after all!).

See als *roto-translation* and *homogeneous transformation*.

Answer (score 2):

A **ray** is a mathematical term that specifies a position and direction without magnitude--and in only 3 letters.